# Change form action url when mobile is detected?

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, action

I'm using a simple form: `<form class="myform" action="desktop.php" method="post" name="none">`

But now I want that he detects when user goes mobile that the form action url is different (mobile.php).  Is that possible? Maybe with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code to check for mobile devices and change the action of your form, and don't forget to include a jQuery CDN too:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('.myform').attr('action', 'mobile.php');
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

what is mobile? a smart phone, a tablet, a subnotebook, a surface tablet with almost a desktop OS?

brance's answer gives you a good approximation that will catch maybe 70% of all mobile user, but there will always be some user that either set their browser to identify as a desktop browser or that use a more exotic browser, that is not identified by the test string. And what if for example the firefoxOS does get some footing in a year or two? you would have to adapt the test string regularly.

The differences between mobile and stationary devices blur more and more. Do you really need the distinction in the form action? maybe, depending on your use case, it would be better to just ask the user (via a checkbox in the form), if they are on a mobile or a stationary device.

a technical idea: 
see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia , there is a javascript API to detect media query attributes. But again, not all browser on a mobile device may have their attributes set in such a way that they are quickly identified as mobile